# How to create phpunit.xml file for the sublime text 3 with package phpunit

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext3

I have installed sublime Text 3 with the package `phpunit` everything installed easily.

then i downloaded and installed `phpunit` for windows platform using the following instructions. https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/installation.html

Now again `phpunit` successfully installed and i have done test they are working fine.

[image]

**So now when i try to run those tests from sublime Text editor then he is asking for `phpunit.xml` file** can anyone tell me where can i find that file or how can i write that file. so that i can run those test from sublime.

**Other problem i am facing when i try to create phpunit.xml file then it asks for various setting and paths like bootstrap.php which i can't find in one phpunit.phar file** so fully confused.

**After Some try on the phpunit.xml file getting error in below image**
[image]

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration & https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: @AlisterBulman  Thanks for your answer but i am using `phpunit6.5.phar` file and for that i don't think `autoload.php` file is needed in `phpunit.xml` file or if needed kindly provide reference Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Eclipse IDE it will help. Easy to setup. You have to just in include the phpunit.phar file into include path.